# How to judge whether model is overfitting or not

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, overfitting, lstm

I am doing video classification with a model combining CNN and LSTM. In the training data, the accuracy rate is 100%, but the accuracy rate of the test data is not so good. The number of training data is small, about 50 per class. In such a case, can I declare that over learning is occurring? Or is there another cause?

Answer (score 1):

To me, accuracy on a training set makes no sense. I ignore it. If you want to test overfitting on training data, you can do this by cross-validation. For details, please see the [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81576/how-to-judge-if-a-supervised-machine-learning-model-is-overfitting-or-not)

Comment: When cross validation is carried out, what kind of accuracy rate value is given when the model is overfitting?

Comment: Please keep in mind that overfitting is not just a yes/not condition. Very different test and train accuracies mean that overfitting is serious.